# HTML button not displaying OpenWeather API Data

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, openweathermap

I have created some code which should display some data from the openweather API after you type in the city and the country. It currently does nothing after clicking on the submit button.

This is my HTML file: Index.html

```
<head>
    <title>Open Weather API</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mainWeather.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="userArea">
        <div id="stateWrapper">
            <input type="text" id="cityInput" placeholder="Enter a State"/>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div id="countryWrapper">
             <input type="text" id="countryInput" placeholder="Enter a Country"/>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div id="buttonArea">
            <input type="submit" id="submitWeather"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!- USED TO SHOW RESULT -->
    <div id="weatherWrapper">
    </div>
</body>
```

In my code I have changed the "Key" to my actual Key

Here is my JavaScript file: mainWeather.js

```
var mainWeather = {
    init: function () {
        $("#submitWeather").click(function () {
            return mainWeather.getWeather();
        });
    },

    getWeather: function () {
        $.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + $("#cityInput").val() + "," + $("#countryInput").val() + "Key", function (data) {
            var json = {
                json: JSON.stringify(data),
                delay: 1
            };
            echo(json);
        });
    },

    //Prints result from the weatherapi, receiving as param an object
    createWeatherWidg: function (data) {
        return "<div class='pressure'> <p>Temperature: " + (data.main.temp - 273.15).toFixed(2) + " C</p></div>" +
            "<div class='description'> <p>Title: " + data.weather[0].main + "</p></div>" +
            "<div class='description'> <p>Description: " + data.weather[0].description + "</p></div>" +
            "<div class='wind'> <p>Wind Speed: " + data.wind.speed + "</p></div>" +
            "<div class='humidity'> <p>Humidity: " + data.main.humidity + "%</p></div>" +
            "<div class='pressure'> <p>Pressure: " + data.main.pressure + " hpa</p></div>";
    }
};

var echo = function (dataPass) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/echo/json/",
        data: dataPass,
        cache: false,
        success: function (json) {
            var wrapper = $("#weatherWrapper");
            wrapper.empty();
            wrapper.append("<div class='city'> <p>Place: " + json.name + ", " + json.sys.country + "</p></div>");
            wrapper.append(mainWeather.createWeatherWidg(json));
        }
    });
};

mainWeather.init();
```

I cant seem to figure out why it isnt working, The two files are in the same folder.

Comment: any errors in console? you said the two files are in the same folder, but in the HTML your `<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/mainWeather.js"></script>` implies it should be in a subfolder called "/resources/js"

Comment: Oh ye sorry, i did have it in that folder but i moved it and forgot to change the code whoops! I have changed the code and it still doesnt work and there are no errors in the console

Answer (score 0):

change

```
    $("#submitWeather").click(function () {
        return mainWeather.getWeather();
    });
```

to

```
    $("#submitWeather").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return mainWeather.getWeather();
    });
```

This:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

will stop the page from posting back. Since "#submitWeather" is an input of type "submit", it's causing a full page postback by default before it ever gets to running the javascript.

Secondly, wrap the whole of mainWeather.js in a $(function() { ... }); block. It occurs to me that the click event handler is being set up before the element it's supposed to be handling has been rendered. The block will make the code wait until the whole document is ready.

Comment: I added the code and it still doesnt seem to work, it wont display the data after clicking the button

Comment: try wrapping the whole of mainWeather.js in a $(function() { ... }); block. It occurs to me that the click event handler is being set up before the element it's supposed to be handling has been rendered. The block will make the code wait until the whole document is ready

Comment: any console / network tab errors this time? I notice you aren't handling the "error" function of your ajax call. So anything that goes wrong calling the API will just get swallowed, from your app's point of view. You might see it in the console. At the very least, add some console.log() calls into your code in various places to see if different parts are being hit or not.

Comment: After clicking the button i get this error -------- XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/echo/json/. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource. --------

Comment: ok 1. I think you should probably remove the first slash from "/echo/json" (so "echo/json"). 2. Sounds like you're just accessing the HTML file directly using file://Index.html in your browser? For a local ajax call to work you need to host it properly in a webserver (can be http://localhost) and access it that way.

Comment: Oh that would make sense sorry i didnt realise i had to do that, how am i able to run it through local host?

Comment: depends on your OS. IIS is normal for Windows, Apache is pretty standard for Linux / OSX. If your Windows version doesn't allow IIS to be used there are several other little webservers available that you could use - just google it. Plenty of docs online about how to enable these and host your pages in them.

Comment: ok thank you, I'll have to wait until i get home because i have a raspberry pi setup with LAMP stack

Comment: yeah that would do it. anyway sounds like your original problem is solved (not triggering the click or calling the data - if you've got to the echo function then the openweather data must have downloaded). So if it's helped please upvote and/or mark as accepted. thanks :-)